# Google Glass Video Capture Intent ignores limit and size extras

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to limit the length of a video captured on Google Glass via the follow code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 10485760); // 10mb in bytes
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.TAKE_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

It appears Glass ignores these extras though. The user still has the option to tap extend and the file size never stops the video either.

Are these extras used in Glass or is this a bug?

EDIT: Filed a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Intent Extras are not actually used by the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` action. Please file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) to track this.

Comment: Thanks Alain. Will do.

Answer (score -1):

Alain, 
this is happening to me as well. 
I submitted Issue 651 for that.

Comment: Alain - since none of the extras are used. What is the best way to retrieve the video file path that I've just recorded using ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE action on Glass?

Comment: Dovik - I believe the standard video path returned from onActivityResult still applies. See https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera#videos.

Comment: Dovik - at the time of you creating that issue my issue 469 I linked was already fixed and implemented in XE20.1.